# React Native ScrollView Snaps back to top

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox, scrollview

I am learning React Native and am having trouble with the ScrollView being able to scroll. Once the scroll surpasses 20-30% of the original screen size it will snap back to the top of the scrollView, hence not letting me scroll to the bottom of my List.

Here is my Code. This screen is loaded directly into App.js which has a flex: 1

```
const LocationsScreen = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Header title={'Locations'} />
            <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.content}>
                <VacationItem location={vacation[3]} />
                <VacationItem location={vacation[1]} />
                <VacationItem location={vacation[0]} />
                <VacationItem location={vacation[3]} />
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.background
    },

    content: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 5,
        alignItems: 'center'
    }

});
```

If anyone had any ideas it would be much appreciated! [image]

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, do you happen to remember what the solution was in the end?